# detect what css attributes are on div to change other div attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes

This div (`ads`) is inside my player. It initially (on page load) doesn't have any `attribute`, but when the close button is clicked, it closes the div by attributing the `style="display: none"`.

What I need to do is to detect when the `div ads` gains the atribute `display:block` to hide the `div hidens`.

The problem seam's to be that when the `div ads` gains the attribute `style="display: block"` my jquery code doesn't detect it so that can change the atribute of the `div hidens` from `style="display: block"` to `style="display: none"`

**This is my code:**

(**Important :** It should work on desktop and mobile devices)

```
<body class="view">
<div class="ads" id="ads">
<div class="close_ads" id="ads_close"></div>
<!-- div ads content and close button here... -->
</div>



<div id="hover_vid" class="fade"><div class="hidens"><button id="close_ho" style="margin-left:5px;float:right;border-color: #fff;" class="button-yes" type="submit" onclick="hide();">X</button>»» content here ««</div></div>

<script>

    function hidethis(){ document.getElementById("hover_vid").style.display="none"; };
    
    
    $(".view").click(function(){
        
        if($("#ads").css("display") == "block" ){
            
            $(".hiden").css("display", "none");
    
        } else if ( $("#ads").css("display") == "none" ) {
            
            $(".hidens").css("display", "block");
            
        } else { 

            
        }

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it your code that adds/removes the `display`?   If so, raise an event at that time and listen for the event.

Comment: Are you referring to the `code` that closes the div `#ads`? If so, the answer is no

Comment: Can you add an event to the click so you also get an event when it closes?  How does it get closed?

Comment: Where is `hide()` defined?

Answer (score -1):

Your example is a little unclear. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#close_ho").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("#hover_vid").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $("#ads.hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#hover_vid {
  margin-top: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2em;
}

#close_ho {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: right;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ads hidden" id="ads">
  <div class="close_ads" id="ads_close"></div>
  <div class="view ad">Ad 1</div>
</div>
<div id="hover_vid" class="fade">
  <div class="hidens"><button id="close_ho" class="button-yes" type="submit">X</button>content here</div>
</div>
```

Assuming an ad is open and on display, when the X is clicked, the ad is hidden and the list of Ads is shown.